# Hasse Invariant of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is there a general method to calculate the Hasse Invariant for any elliptic curve over any finite field?

I have read about the Hasse Invariant on page 140 in 'The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves' but I would like some more explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. In a word, if your curve is $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c=f(x)$, then you look at the coefficient of $x^{p-1}$ in $f^{(p-1)/2}$. That’s the Hasse invariant, and it’s actually there in Th. 4.1(a) on p. 140.
It seems to me that there’s a shorter proof of this single fact — if you’re interested, let me know in a comment, or e-mail me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for an elliptic curve to be supersingular its Hasse invariant must be 0. Over a finite field, in order to have a supersingular curve, does the cefficient of $x^{p-1}$ have to be exactly 0 or is it 0 modulo $p$?

Comment: The elliiptic curve is to be defined over a field (or ring) of characteristic $p$. So there is, in effect, no “modulo $p$”.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I am working with a field of characteristic $p$ with $p^2$ elements and calculating the coefficient of $x^{p-1}$. For the curve to be supersingular should the coefficient be exactly 0 or 0 modulo $p^2$? Thanks

Comment: You’re doing your calculation in a field of characteristic $p$. In your field with $p^2$ elements, all computations have $p=0$. You’re not confusing $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ with $\Bbb Z/(p^2)$, are you?

Comment: Let me give an example for a bit more context. Let's say that I'm trying to determine whether $y^2=x^3-33x+1$ over $F_{11^2}$ is supersingular. I have calculated the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(x^3-33x+1)^5$ to be -660. Do I need to apply any modulo arithmetic to my calculations? Sorry for my confusion.. I am new to elliptic curves.

Comment: Over $\Bbb F_{121}$, your curve is $y^2=x^3+1$. I see that you really are confusing $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ with arithmetic modulo $p^2$. Calling $\Bbb F_{11}=k$, we notice that $2$ is not a square in $k$, so that you can get $\Bbb F_{11^2}$ as $k(\sqrt2\,)$. You should play around in this verdant field.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So over a field $F_{p^2}$ calculations are done modulo $p$?

Comment: Over any field that contains $\Bbb F_p$, calculations are done modulo $p$, because $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($p$ times) is equal to zero there.

Comment: Ok I understand, so for my example that I stated above, $y^2=x^3-33x+1=x^3+1$ since $F_{11^2}$ contains $F_{11}$ . Therefore $y^2=x^3+1$ is supersingular since the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(x^3+1)^5$ is $0$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help Lubin!